# add kenburns effect on background image in css

Tags: html, css, background-image

here is my css

```
#form1 > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.wel-video {
background: url(images/dahua.jpg) no-repeat !important;
/* Make image center */
background-position: center center !important;
/* Make image fixed */
/* Not repeat images */
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
/* Set background size auto */
background-size: auto !important;}
```

i want add to this img the kenburns effect, how can i do this? i try to use webkit but i dont have idea how to do it on background img in css

Comment: Could you describe exactly what effect you want? As I understand it kenburns can mean zooming in/out and panning for example.

Comment: yes sure, i want zooming in

Comment: To start with, avoid the use of `!important`

Answer (score 0):

If you put the image on the before pseudo element rather than the main element itself you can animate that without disturbing the actual element - ie it looks as though the background of the element is changing.

Here's a simple example:

```html
<style>
  .kenburns {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .kenburns::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1024/768);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    animation: kenburns 10s infinite
  }
  
  @keyframes kenburns {
    0%,
    100% {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
      transform: scale(3);
    }
  }
</style>
<div class="kenburns"></div>
```